# sqlite database is locked when creating a table

Tags: java, sqlite

I run this uber simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  Connection c = null;
  Statement stmt = null;
  try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

    stmt = c.createStatement();
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY " +
            "(ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," +
            " NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL, " +
            " AGE            INT     NOT NULL, " +
            " ADDRESS        CHAR(50enter code here), " +
            " SALARY         REAL)";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    stmt.close();
    c.close();
  } catch ( Exception e ) {
    System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
    System.exit(0);
}
System.out.println("Table created successfully");
```

And I'm getting this exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: database is locked.
```

It does not really make any sense, it is just single connection and one operation on the DB.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, show your stack trace, man

Comment: Your code run fine on my machine... How do you compile and run your code? Is that snippet within a larger code that may run in the background?

Comment: Acutely I have solve the problem, looks like the code is broken when you want to store SQLite file on NFS, I moved to local dir and everything works.